# Comic book issue where the Red Skull [sarcastically] calls Captain America gay

Tags: marvel, comics, episode-identification

I remember reading a Captain America story arc where the Red Skull captures Captain America (*I guess*). The Skull the offers Captain America anything he wants in exchange for his support.

During the same conversation, the Red Skull also makes some snarky remarks on Captain America being in a homosexual relationship with Bucky Barnes.

**PS:** I read this comic book a couple of years ago (*2010 - 2012 maybe*); however I'm not sure if it was from the same period or was something really old.

Comment: Take a look at https://readcomiconline.to/Comic/Tales-of-Suspense-1959/Issue-66?id=35598#14 Seems like Red Skull captures Captain America, but all the rest is quite different